# opengl normalized device coordinates larger than 1

Tags: opengl, jogl, projection

I am currently coding a menu system in JAVA and need to convert from world coordinates to screen coordinates. I have read many a post on how to do it and have built the following:

```
    float[] v = new float[]{0,0,0,1}; //four vector location of object in object space


    //multiply by model matrix

    v[0] = model[0]*v[0] + model[4]*v[1] + model[8]*v[2] + model[12]*v[3];
    v[1] = model[1]*v[0] + model[5]*v[1] + model[9]*v[2] + model[13]*v[3];
    v[2] = model[2]*v[0] + model[6]*v[1] + model[10]*v[2] + model[14]*v[3];
    v[3] = model[3]*v[0] + model[7]*v[1] + model[11]*v[2] + model[15]*v[3];

    //multiply by projection matrix

    v[0] = projection[0]*v[0] + projection[4]*v[1] + projection[8]*v[2] + projection[12]*v[3];
    v[1] = projection[1]*v[0] + projection[5]*v[1] + projection[9]*v[2] + projection[13]*v[3];
    v[2] = projection[2]*v[0] + projection[6]*v[1] + projection[10]*v[2] + projection[14]*v[3];
    v[3] = projection[3]*v[0] + projection[7]*v[1] + projection[11]*v[2] + projection[15]*v[3];

    //account for distortions
    v[0] = v[0]/v[3];
    v[1] = v[1]/v[3];
    v[2] = v[2]/v[3];
    v[3] = v[3]/v[3];   

    //transform to screen coords.
    onScreenX = (int)((viewport[2] * (v[0] + 1.0f)) / 2.0f) + viewport[0];
    onScreenY = (int)((viewport[3] * (v[1] + 1.0f)) / 2.0f) + viewport[1];

    System.out.println(onScreenX + ", " + onScreenY);
```

Now the big issue I am having is that after I do the perspective divide I should have values between -1 and 1. However, I get some that are outside of this range even though the object is clearly on the screen. I am not sure what I could be missing here.

I already know of the the function `gluProject()` but this calculation is located far from where my `glu` object is located and so the function would be of no use. It must be done with matrix math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These calculations overwrite values in the `v` vector with new ones, and then use them where the old values should still be used.

Just looking at the first two assignments:

```
v[0] = model[0]*v[0] + model[4]*v[1] + model[8]*v[2] + model[12]*v[3];
v[1] = model[1]*v[0] + model[5]*v[1] + model[9]*v[2] + model[13]*v[3];
```

The first statement assigns a new value to `v[0]`, and then uses it on the right side of the second statement. So for the calculation of `v[1]`, the new value for `v[0]` is used together with the old values of `v[1]`, `v[2]` and `v[3]`.

The same pattern continues through the entire calculations.

The easiest way to avoid this is to use a new vector for each step of the calculation. For example:

```
float[] vModel = new float[4];
vModel[0] = model[0]*v[0] + model[4]*v[1] + model[8]*v[2] + model[12]*v[3];
vModel[1] = model[1]*v[0] + model[5]*v[1] + model[9]*v[2] + model[13]*v[3];
...

float[] vProj = new float[4];
vProj[0] = projection[0]*vModel[0] + ...
...
```

This avoids overwriting values with new ones while the old one is still in use.

Comment: o.O I must have been working on this code for too long to miss such a simple bug. Thank you so much for pointing that out. Works like a dream now.